# Mongo shell not showing content

Tags: node.js, mongodb, shell, express

I have created a web app with nodejs and express. I am using mongolian for connecting with mongo db.

Although i am getting right data in my GET requests, when i try to see the data in the shell, i do not see any.

Here is the log:

```
mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-2.4.9\bin>mongod.exe --dbpath data\db
Sun Feb 23 20:24:03.176 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=8736 port=27017 d
bpath=data\db 64-bit host=asnegi-w7
Sun Feb 23 20:24:03.179 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.9
Sun Feb 23 20:24:03.180 [initandlisten] git version: 52fe0d21959e32a5bdbecdc6205
7db386e4e029c
Sun Feb 23 20:24:03.181 [initandlisten] build info: windows sys.getwindowsversio
n(major=6, minor=1, build=7601, platform=2, service_pack='Service Pack 1') BOOST
_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Sun Feb 23 20:24:03.182 [initandlisten] allocator: system
Sun Feb 23 20:24:03.182 [initandlisten] options: { dbpath: "data\db" }
Sun Feb 23 20:24:03.196 [initandlisten] journal dir=data\db\journal
Sun Feb 23 20:24:03.196 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no r
ecovery needed
Sun Feb 23 20:24:03.337 [websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on po
rt 28017
Sun Feb 23 20:24:03.337 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
Sun Feb 23 20:24:29.664 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:56639
 #1 (1 connection now open)
Sun Feb 23 20:27:20.849 [conn1] end connection 127.0.0.1:56639 (0 connections no
w open)
Sun Feb 23 20:28:08.538 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:56687
 #2 (1 connection now open)
Sun Feb 23 20:28:58.317 [conn2] end connection 127.0.0.1:56687 (0 connections no
w open)
Sun Feb 23 20:29:03.051 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:56702
 #3 (1 connection now open)
Sun Feb 23 20:29:40.585 [conn3] end connection 127.0.0.1:56702 (0 connections no
w open)
Sun Feb 23 20:29:43.971 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:56707
 #4 (1 connection now open)
Sun Feb 23 20:30:18.166 [conn4] end connection 127.0.0.1:56707 (0 connections no
w open)
Sun Feb 23 20:30:22.999 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:56712
 #5 (1 connection now open)
```

and for the shell:

```
mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-2.4.9\bin>mongo.e
xe
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: test
> show dbs
bluff_message_db        0.203125GB
local   0.078125GB
message_db      0.203125GB
session_db      0.203125GB
> use session_db;
switched to db session_db
> show collections;
system.indexes
> show collection
Sun Feb 23 20:25:00.362 don't know how to show [collection] at src/mongo/shell/u
tils.js:847
> show collections
system.indexes
> db.sessions
session_db.sessions
> db.sessions.find()
> show dbs
bluff_message_db        0.203125GB
local   0.078125GB
message_db      0.203125GB
session_db      0.203125GB
> use message_db
switched to db message_db
> show collections
messsages
system.indexes
> use messages
switched to db messages
> db.messages
messages.messages
> db.messages.find()
>
```

and it shows no output.

i noticed `connecting to: test` in the shell. i gave parameters like dev, prod in the command line like `mongo.exe prod` but nothing worked. All of them shows the dbs and messages but not content.

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a spelling mistake in your collection name. You have `messsages` with **three "s" characters**.

I'm assuming that this is simply a "typo" in the shell.Muscle memory made you type the "correct" spelling of "messages" even though the actual collection name has errors in it.

Mongo will allow you to switch to/ use databases, collections even if they do not yet exist. The moment you try to insert a document - the structure is created.